# How should I deal with this answer

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10257001/212940, made by the OP to his own question includes another question.

My instinct is to edit out the question bit and possibly transfer it into the question, leaving the answer part. Is this the correct thing to do here?

If not how should it be dealt with? The OP seems to be mistaking SO for a forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making an edit like that and adding a comment would be perfectly reasonable. It saves moderator time and there clearly is valuable content in there.

The poster probably "learns" about the Q&A vs forum style and the question still gets an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and did it.